# What is the risk, giving users email addresses on a domain name?

Tags: email

Say I have a website at www.example.org

For the sake of painting a meaningful story, say I am going to give each user a web page at www.example.org/username and an email address at username@example.org

What are the risks of giving users that email address, aside from the possibility that they might send spam?

To clarify, in response to comment.  At first I wondered if maybe being able to accept email at that domain might risk domain hijacking somehow, and then I vaguely thought that perhaps there are other ways that people might pretend that are from the "Example Org" company, as proven by having an address at that domain.  On the other hand it can't be too risky I suppose because handing out email addresses is exactly what all email providers do.  It's a vague concern but I did not want to not fully understand potential risks before implementing it, thus the question to the security experts.

Comment: I find asking about the risks of issuing email addresses a little general. Are there specific aspects you're interested in? (Also, distributing sites at `www.example.org/username` would be insecure because then all user sites are seen by your browser as the same origin.)

Comment: @arminius I have updated the question with clarification.

Comment: @Arminius: While I agree the question is way too broad, your assertion "would be insecure because then all user sites are seen by your browser as the same origin" is not a direct corollary - its quite possible to have complete isolation of the sites under the same (public) hostname, e.g. by splitting the traffic on a reverse proxy across dedicated hosts/containers or providing only static content hosting and a chroot upload facility. However given the way the question has been presented, wider security issues seem inevitable.

Comment: @symcbean I was hinting at SOP-related (client-side) problems due to the fact that `example.org/you` and `example.org/me` are both on the same origin from your browser's point of view, even if the content is hosted on isolated servers.

Comment: @Arminus: but I'm struggling to imagine what harm could be achieved in absence of other capabilities which we don't know about (such as an application tier or websockets). I'll have a think about it and maybe post a question unless you suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

I see the risk that people can pretend that they are from the example.org company.

[Rfc2142](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2142.txt) describes internet mail addresses to be used when contacting personnel at an organization, for example abuse@example.org to report inappropriate public behavior of your server like sending spam. Other special mail addresses are postmaster or webmaster.

If someone can take one of these addresses there is the risk that someone can impersonate as an administrative user. The resulting risk depends on how much someone trust these users. Therefore I would ensure that it is impossible to use the usernames definend in Rfc2142.

Comment: There already where cases where users registered ``ssladmin@`` on a free mail service and then obtained a domain validated certificate. This is a real security risk if you don't blacklist such aliases.

Answer (score 0):

> aside from the possibility that they might send spam?

The ability to send email is something different the ability to receive email. So its trivial to eliminate that risk. However it does imply that you have a lot of learning to do before you are in position to ensure the security of the service as a whole - and perhaps more support that Q&A here.

Then there's the question of whether you intend providing the ability (and facilities) to retrieve mail from the server (you could just provision forwarding) or to read mail on the server.

Without knowing any more about the infrastructure and the specifics of the services it is impossible to enumerate all the issues created by running both a webservice **and** an email service (as opposed to the separate list of potential issues with a mail service and the list for a web service).

Answer (score 0):

Some points I can immediately think about:

- email addresses should never contain admin, root, master, abuse or owner (not exhaustive list), or their equivalent in your language(s)
- email addresses should not give account connection (through ssh, telnet or ftp) on your system (a real user with that name should not exist)
- email addresses should not give access to shared ressources on your system

This is for technical system protection from users

Some other points:

- you should never store the passwords in invertible format but only hashes form them
- you should clearly identify who can access the mailboxes from the system
- you should provide your users a *contract* stating what you are responsable for, what they are allowed to do, and how you process their data (user address, password, mails content), and who can access to it in what context

This is for your protection from possible legal actions for not correctly protecting the privacy/confidentiality of your users, or not providing enough availability or integrity assurance (disclaimer: I Am Not A Lawyer, so I have just imagined possible implications of the CIA triad)